# WP-CLI Error Requesting CURL Extension

Tags: multisite, wp-cli

Instantly fell in love with WP-Cli... life at real speed, ditch the GUI.. :-)

Each time that I run a command, it executes successfully, however I get the following error message and warning:

```
<br/><b style='font-size:16px; color:red;'>curl_exec function is disabled in php.ini</b> - <i style='font-size:12px; color:red;'>Social Networks AutoPoster needs the CURL PHP extension. Please enable it or contact your hosting company to enable it.</i><br/><br/>Installing Multisite Toolbar Additions (2.0.1)
Warning: Failed to create directory '/home/user/.wp-cli/cache/': mkdir(): Permission denied.
Downloading installation package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/multisite-toolbar-additions.2.0.1.zip...
Unpacking the package...
Installing the plugin...
Plugin installed successfully.
Network-activating 'multisite-toolbar-additions'...
Plugin 'multisite-toolbar-additions' network activated.
Success: Installed 1 of 1 plugins.
```

However the output of https://localhost.sitedomain.com/phpinfo.php  confirms that curl support is stalled properly

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like a WP CLI error, the error message is formatted in HTML and names a plugin, are you sure this is a WP CLI problem and not a bug in that plugin?

Comment: not sure at all.. completely new to wp-cli..  Its just that I don't receive any error message or warning via the gui...

Comment: `Social Networks AutoPoster needs the CURL PHP extension.`, keep in mind that PHP FPM/CGI-BIN isn't quite the same as PHP CLI. Just because you have an extension listed in PHP info when you load it in the browser, doesn't mean it's present on CLI. You would need to run PHP Info via CLI and compare the output. But that's a dev ops problem not a WP problem. For `Social Networks AutoPoster` you should contact their support, plugins and themes can still misbehave and generate warnings on CLI just like they would in the browser, except it's harder to hide warnings and errors

Comment: Ok will do... thx for the follow up

Comment: What about the Warning: Failed to create directory '/home/user/.wp-cli/cache/': mkdir(): Permission denied.  Warning

Comment: the user you're running WP CLI as can't create that folder, but it doesn't prevent WP CLI from working, it just means it has to download each time rather than caching plugin zip files too speed things up later. You can try creating the folder manually

Comment: Just to tag on to @TomJNowell 's comment, you can try `php -i |grep -i curl` to see what the CLI binary supports as far as cURL.

Answer (score 0):

Though, curl appeared to be properly working from  https://localhost.sitedomain.com/phpinfo.php , the true cause of the error was that curl was in fact disabled within the global php.ini file located at `/etc/php/<php version #>/php.ini` , which is different from local active php.ini located at `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini` . Now everything works properly.